# running same javascript file more than once on a page

Tags: javascript

I would like to include the same javascript file more than once on a page. This is because different variables are defined using the "data" attr to get different data.

Here is an example of what i mean:

```
<script id="sc_widget" data-key="rsl2xlfiovx09mkwofom" data-id="jwks97n15dpqge35jfmm" src="http://example.co.uk/sc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script id="sc_widget" data-key="rsl2xlfiovx09mkwofom" data-id="fw8zy246n8vhf5f8du7n" src="http://example.co.uk/sc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The above obviously detects and displays the information from the script twice, but the information displayed is the same for both, when it should be different.

My js file:

```
var key = document.getElementById("sc_widget").getAttribute("data-key");
    var id = document.getElementById("sc_widget").getAttribute("data-id");
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "//example.co.uk/sc.php?key="+ key + "&id="+ id,
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            $('.sc_ouput').html(responseData);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    })
```

So is there anyway to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you add the code showing how the script is reading the `data-*` attributes?

Comment: Although you can, it is bad practice to use a single id on multiple elements.

Comment: @phuzi this will get changes to a class

Comment: @JamesThorpe i ahve added my js.

Comment: @phuzi — "Although you can, it is bad practice to use a single id on multiple elements" — No. It is **forbidden** to reuse ids.

Comment: @Quentin, browser won't complain about it though and it won't necessarily cause any problems it could.

Comment: @phuzi — Browsers recover from a lot of errors. It doesn't make it any less wrong. It **is** the cause of this problem.

Comment: How is the "data-id" or the "script" tag being generated? Couldn't you replace with another tag and then call a sigle javascript that analyzes those tags? And, as previous users mentioned, you should not have the same id in these tags...

Comment: @Quentin granted. My comments were made before OP added their JavaScript

Answer (score 2):

`id` attributes must be **unique** in an HTML document.

`document.getElementById("sc_widget")` will always get the *first* element with the matching ID. The others will be ignored as the browser attempts to recover from the error.

Instead, get the *last* `<script>` element in the document.

```
var scripts = document.querySelectorAll("script");
var script = scripts[scripts.length - 1];
var key = script.dataset.key;
var id = script.dataset.id;
```

---

You'll also need to change this logic:

> ```
> $('.sc_ouput').html(responseData);
> ```

… since it replaces the content of the first element that is a member of that class.

Possibly you'll want to use some logic such as replacing the previous sibling of the `script` element you've already found.

Note that since you are using an asynchronous function inside the script, you'll need to wrap it in an IIFE to close over the `script` variable so it doesn't get overwritten by the next script before the Ajax has finished.

Comment: The question clearly states that both scripts should be taken in account. Getting the last one instead won't help. Additionally, querying by `'script'` is error prone and misses the chance to resolve one of the main errors the question.

Comment: @Barthy — Getting the *last* one **will** help because the last one will be *the script that has just loaded*. So when the first script loads, it will be the last one. Later, the second script will load and then the second one will be the last one. This only gets error prone if you do things like `defer`, which these scripts are not.

Comment: Alright, I did not know that. To improve the quality of your answer, you should write that down, too. I removed my downvote.

Comment: May be worth noting that [`document.currentScript`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript) is now fairly widely supported too - I think this would also then work for `async` and `defer` scripts.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to include the same javascript file more than once on a
>   page.

You don't need to include and re-include the same file.

You simply need to write a function which takes one or more parameters:

```
function myFunction(fruit) {

/* [... CODE HERE ...] */

}
```

if you want to run the script once on the data `apple` and once on the data `banana`, you can then do the following:

```
myFunction(apple);
myFunction(banana);
```